# Why is Dalinar's Blade screaming?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

Spoilers for the *Stormlight Archive*.

At the end of *Words of Radiance*, when the Stormfather bonds with Dalinar, he asks Dalinar to divest himself of that "monstrosity", the Blade he's currently bonded to. When he summons the Blade to do so, he can feel the screaming from the Blade in his head.

However:

1. This screaming seems to be a property of the Blades that come from the original Knights Radiant. I think it's the screaming of the dead (?) spren who forms the Blade.
2. Honorblades don't cause this screaming. At least, the Honorblade that Szeth used didn't cause any screaming for Kaladin. And Honorblades aren't formed of spren, so there should be nothing to do the screaming.
3. It seems that the Dalinar bonded with Talenel's Honorblade. He tells Amaram that the Blade hidden in the cavern is Talenel's, and that he bonded with that Blade because he didn't want to risk losing it.

So why is Dalinar hearing screaming? Did he bond to another Blade after the confrontation with Amaram? Is Talenel's Blade not really an Honorblade?

---

In [chapter 16 of *Oathbringer*](https://www.tor.com/2017/10/03/oathbringer-by-brandon-sanderson-chapters-16-18/), Dalinar can hold Szeth's Honorblade without hearing any screaming, and the Stormfather confirms that Honorblades don't have minds to scream.

Comment: Oh man, we can actually answer this now that Rhythm of War is out...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### It wasn’t an Honorblade

Straight from [the author himself](http://faq.brandonsanderson.com/node/461):

> The one that characters obtained in Words of Radiance is NOT an
>   Honorblade.  It’s an ordinary shardblade (as ordinary as one of those
>   can be called.) I’m not going to say specifically what happened to the
>   Blade Taln arrived with at Kholinar, but I will say that it IS a
>   different weapon from the one in Words of Radiance.

Brandon’s not saying what happened to Talenel’s Honorblade, but in the same discussion he mentions that someone can hold an Honorblade and not know how to use its powers, suggesting that somehow it was swapped with an ordinary shardblade. So someone out there is walking around with an Honorblade, not realizing what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

following up @Adamant response

The way the author answer that, making emphasys on Kholinar where Talanel arrived, I think it gives hints that Hoid probably had something to do with the swapping as he was there...

Comment: These seems oddly similar to the answer above it, you've used the same quote and the exact same logic.

Comment: you are right, i'll edit it and just leave my small addition about hoid...

Answer (score 0):

The Stormfather says in Oathbringer that it is not an Honorblade and he doesn't know what happened to the Honorblade

Comment: That could probably use a quote or something to make for a better answer... It's a bit terse at the moement